# How do I compute this integral without Γ?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $M = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0 \leq y \leq \sqrt2, y^2 \leq x \leq 2\}$.
Compute $\iint_M y^3 e^{x^3} \,dx \,dy$

Comment: Why do you think that you need $\Gamma$. What have you tried ?

Comment: well I took $y^3$ in front because it is a constant then I viewed $e^{x^3}$ as an incomplete gamma function.

Comment: Hint: Integrate along $y$ first (taking the domain restriction involving $x$ into account).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that the integral is

$$\int_0^2e^{x^3}\Bigg[\int_0^{\sqrt{x}}y^3 dy\Bigg]dx=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^2 x^2 e^{x^3}dx$$

which looks like an immediate integral